# Calendar & subscriptions modules

Tags: datetime, notifications

Is it possible for anonymos users to subscribe to calendar events created using the Calendar module? If so, how would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible for anonymos users to subscribe to calendar events created using the Calendar module.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about adjusting the setting sto enable this? @NikHilM

Comment: i think Full Calendar module is a better solution and it works well with Date Api

Comment: Thank you @PreritMohan
Is it completely configurable or do I need to insert some PHP code? In order to enable users to subscribe to Events created using Full Calendar?